# Finding the set of n equally distant points

Tags: r, vector, distance

For simplicity, if I have a vector of points which looks something like:

```
x = c(1,4,5,8,9)
```

I'm trying to find the `n` points which are equidistant from one another. In this case my `n=3` so my ideal answer would be:

1,5,9

Since `5-1=4` and `9-5=4`.

The actual vectors are much larger/complex as well as `n`. 
Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To be honest I don't get why `1,5,9` are equidistant. A point is said to be equidistant from a set of objects if the distances between that point and each object in the set are equal.

Comment: Why "most likely" equidistant?  Equidistance is either true or false, right?  A set is equidistant if the distance between any two points in the set is the same real number.  In your example, 1,5,9 is not equidistant since |5-1| != |9-1|.

Comment: It seems like there could be several vectors of length `n` that would be equidistant, especially if `length(x)` is large, and `n` is small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the whole solution, but I think it is the start of one. First, computing the distance matrix will probably be helpful.

```
> x <- c(1,4,5,8,9)
> dx <- dist(x)
> dx
  1 2 3 4
2 3      
3 4 1    
4 7 4 3  
5 8 5 4 1
```

Second, you can identify points which are the same distance apart by sorting the distances and run-length encoding them.

```
> rdx <- rle(sort(dx))
> rdx
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:6] 2 2 3 1 1 1
  values : num [1:6] 1 3 4 5 7 8
```

you can select the set of points you want and then get back to the indices in the original distance matrix using the `order` function. Taking the third group -- of points separated by distance 4 -- as an example

```
> i=3
> orderedIndex <- sum(rdx$lengths[1:(i-1)])
> order(dx)[(orderedIndex+1):(orderedIndex+rdx$lengths[i])]
[1] 2 6 9
```

(the indices count from the top down then from left to right). So here you have identified the `4`s in the distance matrix: these are distances between the 1st/3rd, 2nd/4th, and 3rd/5th points in `x`. But you still have to do some more work to eliminate the 2nd and 4th points. Presumably you choose the 1st, 3rd and 5th points because they are connected?

I think you would want to process all groups of points identified by the `rle` function as over your chosen size, and then check for connectivity.

Comment: PS there is a [great answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17191756/834521) as to how to go from the index in a distance matrix back to (row,columns)

Answer (score 1):

Consistent with comments above, here's something that might be what you want, not necessarily what you ask for.  I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this, though.

```
x = c(1,4,5,8,9)
x2 <- as.matrix(expand.grid(x, x))
x2 <- as.data.frame(t(apply(x2, 1, sort)))
x2 <- x2[!duplicated(x2), ]
x2 <- cbind(x2, d =abs(mapply("-", x2[,1], x2[,2])))
x2[order(x2$d), ]
# V1 V2 d
# 1   1  1 0
# 7   4  4 0
# 13  5  5 0
# 19  8  8 0
# 25  9  9 0
# 8   4  5 1
# 20  8  9 1
# 2   1  4 3
# 14  5  8 3
# 3   1  5 4
# 9   4  8 4
# 15  5  9 4
# 10  4  9 5
# 4   1  8 7
# 5   1  9 8
```