# How do I go from cell given by dist back to row and column numbers

Tags: r

Say I have

```
> x<-1:5
> dist(x)
  1 2 3 4
2 1      
3 2 1    
4 3 2 1  
5 4 3 2 1
> which(dist(x)==max(dist(x)))
[1] 4
```

How do I get from the index `4` back to the row and column numbers `(5,1)`?

Comment: dist(x) returns an atomic vector. It only 'prints' a matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There might be a tidier way ...

```
dist.x <- dist(x)
which(as.matrix(dist.x) == max(dist.x) & lower.tri(dist.x), arr.ind=TRUE)
#   row col
# 5   5   1
```

Comment: +1 nice and simple, exactly what i'd do.

Comment: +1 - also `which(lower.tri(dist.x), arr.ind=TRUE)[which.max(dist.x), ]`

Answer (score 2):

dist has a method to as.matrix which is useful. You can try this:

```
kk <- as.matrix(dist(x))
which(kk == max(kk), arr.ind=TRUE)
```

For your example,

```
  row col
5   5   1
1   1   5
```

Comment: Matthew has already given this *exact* answer above (as had I, but I deleted mine because it was duplicate info and he answered first).

Answer (score 1):

`dist` returns an object of class "dist."  You should start by reading the help file, which says:

```
Value

dist returns an object of class "dist".

The lower triangle of the distance matrix stored by columns in a vector, say do. If n is the number of observations, i.e., n <- attr(do, "Size"), then for i < j ≤ n, the dissimilarity between (row) i and j is do[n*(i-1) - i*(i-1)/2 + j-i]. The length of the vector is n*(n-1)/2, i.e., of order n^2.
```

The other answers posted modify the "dist" object in useful ways for you.